# Do I need to manually generate static sites for nextjs?

Tags: next.js

I have a Nextjs site with over 300,000 pages. very low traffic at the moment so I hope I can improve it by using SEO.

I've selected Incremental Site Regeneration option so only 700+ pages were created at build time. For the remaining pages, do I have to manually open the rest of the documents / pages so that the static pages can be created for search engines to crawl? I'm thinking of using some automated downloader / scraper to do this as I have all the web addresses.

I have also uploaded sitemaps but Google has not accepted/fetch them (I was told this could take weeks). I think if I have static pages ready, it could improve my site's discoverability.

Comment: Have you mentioned all the pages in your sitemap?

Comment: If your pages link to other pages that would also be picked up by crawlers.